# Why doesn't changing my default name servers in WebHost Manager take effect?

Tags: configuration, nameserver

I'm using cPanel/WHM 11.28.87, and when I go into "Basic cPanel & WHM Setup" in WebHost Manager and change my default nameservers at the bottom of the page, save, and re-open "Basic cPanel & WHM Setup", the nameservers are right back to how they were!

I *can* change other items on this same page, like the default shared IP address.

[image: Screen Capture 1]
[image: Screen Capture 2]
[image: Screen Capture 3]

Anyone know what file on disk these are stored in so I can just go and edit them myself?

**EDIT:** Darryl at NetHosted told me the file is `/etc/wwwacct.conf`... but I just edited that file and *it already contained the correct name servers!* So WHM is pulling the old name servers from somewhere else...

**EDIT 2:** Restarting cPanel / WHM via `/etc/init.d/cpanel restart` does not solve this issue either, I should have mentioned I tried that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HopelessN00b This question is **on topic** because it is about managing the hardware or software of servers while working as a sysadmin for a service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug with cPanel. The name servers I was seeing were my *reseller's* name servers. Yet it was showing them to me in the wrong place.

This seems to be corrected in the current version. But ultimately the fix was to correct the name servers under **Reseller Center**.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the default nameservers in the /etc/wwwacct.conf file they are stored in the format

```
NS ns1.nameserver.com
NS2 ns2.nameserver.com
NS3
NS4
```

editing this file directly should work.

Comment: Wow, the plot thickens! I opened that file and *it already contained the correct name servers!* Yet, WHM still lists the old name servers and creates accounts with the old name servers!

Comment: It might be worth trying a forced cPanel update to see if this helps: `/scripts/upcp -force`